# Sort field by specifically formated date

Tags: php, mysql

i have a field called registration date which saves date in this format in php mysql,

```
$userregdate= date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

gives me this kind of output

```
2015-08-10 11:49:40
```

kindly can you please help me in how i can sort by this field?

Comment: how about `order by regdate`

Comment: Try someghing like this "SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY `your_date_field` DESC");

Comment: ASC or DESC whatever floats your boat

Comment: **@Drew & Asim Shahzad**: As you are trying to giving an answer so **Post Your Answer** is a better choice than comment.

Comment: @Chayan They're doing just fine